# How to reuse type declaration of entire package?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Assuming that I have a monorepo with structure like this:

```
├── packages
│   ├── foo
│       ├── a.js
│       ├── index.js
│       ├── index.d.ts
│       ├── package.json      
├── tsconfig.json
```

`foo` is a legacy packge written in JavaScript, and the `index.js` file exports all available objects that may be imported by other packages.

Recently, I wrote a declaration file `index.d.ts` for this package, which looks like:

```
foo/index.d.ts
declare module 'foo' {
  // export all available object here
  export const something: SomeThing
  ...
}
```

Now, I want to add a file `b.ts` under package `foo`:

```
foo/b.ts
import { something } from './a' // error: can not find the declaration file of the module ...
```

As I expected, it occurs error, though I have make type declaration in `index.d.ts`.

Through my attempts, I found that redeclaring an `a.d.ts` file solves this problem：

```
foo/a.d.ts
export const something: SomeThing
```

besides, I can also solve it not using relative import：

```
foo/b.ts
import { something } from 'foo'
```

however, this solution looks strange, I am not sure if it would cause module circular dependency.

Is there any other way which can reuse the type declaration in `index.d.ts` with minimal change?

Answer (score 0):

Change tsconfig.json file add include like this code.

```
{
  "include": ["foo/**/*"]
}
```